# Adding a book to a list with a has_many :through association and using the best_in_place gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, best-in-place

I have 3 models `User` `Book` and `List`. They each have a relationship with each other. Pretty much what i'm trying to do it add a book to a users list. I'm using the best_in_place gem to update the book from the users list in the books show.html.erb. When i try to update the status it just goes back to blank. I'm not entirely sure why it's not updating. Maybe someone can checkout my code and see if i'm missing something.

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base 
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :book
 validates :book, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id, message: "%{attribute} already added" } 
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :lists
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :lists
 has_many :books, through: :lists
end
```

Lists controller

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
 respond_to :html, :json

 def create
  @book = Book.find params[:book_id]
  @list = current_user.lists.new list_params
  @list.save
 end

 def update
  @book = Book.find params[:book_id]
  @list = current_user.lists.find(params[:id])
  @list.update (list_params)
  respond_with @list
 end

 def destroy
  @book = Book.find params[:book_id]
  @list = current_user.lists.find(params[:id]).destroy
 end

 private

 def list_params
  params.require(:list).permit(:status, :rating).merge(book_id: @book.id)
 end
end
```

Books controller

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
 def show
  @book = Book.find params[:id]
  @list = current_user.lists.new
 end
end
```

books/show.html.erb

```
<%= best_in_place [@book, @list], :status, type: :select,
    collection: [["Watching" , "Watching"],
    ["Completed" , "Completed"], 
    ["On-Hold" , "On-Hold"], 
    ["Dropped" , "Dropped"], 
    ["Plan to Read" , "Plan to REad"]],
    class: 'small dropdown button' %>
```

Comment: you might want read documentation carefully. you might have to add in book controller: respond_with_bip

Answer (score 1):

There are some syntax errors:
- No brackets after the find method in some cases
- Your book controller is called "ListsController"

Moreover I would make Book belong to List, not the other way round. It sounds more logical.
Also I would not make Book belong to User if the users only own book through lists..

Another thing, in your Book controller. Why do you create a new list when you show a book ?

I cant comment on the Best-in-place gem. But after correcting a few things you may have it working

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong. A book belongs to a list and a list has many books?

Comment: This is correct. then your model List should "have_many books" not List "belongs_to" books. But it just may work your way too. this is just more logical this way.